# Norm of "canonical" double dual mapping

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Given a normed linear space $V$, define the injection from $V$ to its double dual $V''$ as:
$$f_v(\alpha) = \alpha(v)$$
for fixed $\alpha\in V'$ (is this the correct definition?). Prove that $\|f_v\| = \|v\|$.

My attempt:
We have that:

$$\|f_v\| = \sup_{\|\alpha\| = 1}\|f_v(\alpha)\| = \sup_{||\alpha|| = 1}\|\alpha(v)|| \leq ||a|| \cdot ||v|| = ||v||$$

So we have one side of the inequality. I want to prove the other, namely that $||f_v|| \geq \|v\|$. Am I proceeding correctly so far? How should I proceed further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Hahn-Banach extension theorem for nonzero $v$, one can find some $\alpha\in V'$ such that $\|\alpha\|=1$, $\alpha(v)=\|v\|$, then you may proceed successfully.

In fact, let $Y=\left<v\right>$ and define $\alpha_{0}(kv)=k\|v\|$, then Hahn-Banach extension says that there is an extension $\alpha$ such that $\|\alpha\|=\|\alpha_{0}\|=1$.

Comment: Sorry, I am slightly confused as to how hahn-banach can be used to show the existence of such a functional. Would you mind explaining?

Comment: I have added the details.

Comment: Thank you. A small clarification: it seems that $a_0$ is not linear. Why then would hahn-banach apply?

Comment: $\alpha_{0}((k+m)v)=(k+m)\|v\|=k\|v\|+m\|v\|=\alpha_{0}(kv)+\alpha_{0}(mv)$.